# How to add two different search box for two different column in bootstrap-vue table

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I need two search boxes for two different table columns, both search boxes are work like "AND" conditions.

Here is the image what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: Please, read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, so people could help you.

Comment: Thank you @muka.gergely and James A Mohler. this is my first post, from now on I will take care of how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is NOT to worry about those two columns in the table - just handle the data that fills up those columns (and the table):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(e => {
        return Object.keys(this.filters).every(el => {
          // .toLowerCase() makes this filter case insensitive
          return this.filters[el] === '' || String(e[el]).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filters[el].toLowerCase()) !== -1
        })
      })
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      gradeOptions: ['', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
      filters: {
        age: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        grade: ''
      },
      items: [{
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald',
          grade: 'A'
        },
        {
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw',
          grade: 'B'
        },
        {
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shawn',
          grade: 'C'
        },
        {
          age: 89,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson',
          grade: 'B'
        },
        {
          age: 38,
          first_name: 'Jami',
          last_name: 'Carney',
          grade: 'A'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-input v-model="filters.age" placeholder="Filter age"></b-form-input>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-input v-model="filters.first_name" placeholder="Filter firstname"></b-form-input>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-input v-model="filters.last_name" placeholder="Filter lastname"></b-form-input>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-select v-model="filters.grade" :options="gradeOptions"></b-form-select>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <div>
          <b-table striped hover :items="filteredItems"></b-table>
        </div>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
```

In my snippet, the `filteredItems` computed property returns only those objects that satisfy the corresponding filter (or if the corresponding filter is empty). The `every` function ensures that the filters are bound by an `AND` logic.

I use the `filteredItems` to fill up the table (not the `items` directly), thus I have a better control over what data set should appear in the table.

**The main point is:** you shouldn't filter *two columns* of the table, you should filter *the data* behind the table - with filtered data the table works as it should.

Comment: what if I have one more filter based on a `select` tag. let's assume I have a category column in the table. and in the `select` tag, all categories are mentioned. if I select any category then the table has to filter.

Comment: @RonakPanchal I updated my answer with a simple `select` solution. The problem comes in when two options resemble each other, like: `female` & `male`. By choosing `male`, you would get all `female`s too. In this more advanced case, the filtering function has to be upgraded, so it knows in which cases should it look for full equality. Maybe you could add a `comparisonType` (`full || partial`) to the filters, so during filtering you can also differentiate by that value. I'm sorry, but I don't have the time now to handle this more complex case.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.